# jquery DOM object wrapped in a tag ends up on its own?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to wrap a jQuery object in a list. The object is

```
<a class="medium button" title="Title"">Sample</a>
```

and the interaction

```
$(".medium").click(function() {
  $(".list4").append("<li>");
  $(".list4").append($(this));
  $(".list4").append("</li>");
});
```

but this inevitably ends up in a blank list item. But if I do something like

```
$(".medium").click(function() {
  $(".list4").append("<li>");
  $(".list4").append($(this).html());
  $(".list4").append("</li>");
});
```

the item doesn't have the link. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
$(".medium").click(function() {
  $("<li />").append(this).appendTo('.list4');
});
```

or if you want to leave the element at it's original place, you can `clone` it:

```
$("<li />").append($(this).clone()).appendTo('.list4');
```

As [@Marc B already explained in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194373/jquery-dom-object-wrapped-in-a-tag-ends-up-on-its-own/7194398#7194398), every `append` inserts a new DOM node, not just HTML text. When you call `$element.append('<div>')`, then the browser (or even jQuery) will correct the "broken" HTML.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.list4').append('<li>' + $(this).html() + '</li>');
```

each append operation generates at least one new node. Calling it 3 times like that generates 3 new nodes. So... embed a full HTML snippet to be appended, which'll generate just one new `<li>`

Comment: +1 - OP, you're effectively inserting three nodes into the list, not raw HTML.

Comment: This answer inspired me to create a div for each `.medium` object, like `<div class='holder'><a class="medium button" title="Title"">Sample</a></div>` and using `$('.list4').append('<li>' + $(this).parent().html() + '</li>');`

Comment: @Marc B - `$(this).html()` will only return "Sample". You'll lose the hyperlink this way.

Comment: @65FBef05. true enough. easy to work around, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Comment: @Marc B - Thanks for the link. After reading through the answers, I was inspired to turn my answer below into a plugin. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".medium").click(function() {
  $(".list4").append("<li></li>");
  $(".list4 li").append($(this));
});
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: `$(this)` returns an object, not a string.

Comment: @65fbef05 I know, but jQuery is smart enough to figure it out.  It's a neat trick I learned a while back. :)

Comment: Hmm... Interesting and good to know. I'll toy around with it a bit.